# Javascript preview box replace \n with <br>

Tags: javascript, html, preview

I have a textarea that updates a div below for a preview box. The issue is when u hit enter, in the preview box it should also put an enter. But what it does is 1 time change \n to br then the others just get replaced with a space. I dont generally use javascript so im confuzzled.

My code:

```
<div class='fl' ><textarea id='textbox' onkeyup="document.getElementById('preview').innerHTML=document.getElementById('textbox').value.replace('\n','<br />');" name='description' class='arial f12' style='width:400px;height:200px;resize:vertical;'></textarea></div>
<div id='preview' class='f12 arial p10' style='background-color:#efefef;'></div>
```

Example:

> 1
>   2
>   3
>    4

comes out as:

> 1
>    2 3 4

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where it says `.replace('\n','<br />')` use this instead `.replace(/\n/g,'<br />')`

The `/g` means "global" as in "replace *all* matches". Without it, only the first match gets replaced

Comment: lol that was easy, thanks. Really had no clue what that was so I deleted it originally.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
value.replace(/\n/g,'<br />')

<div class='fl' ><textarea id='textbox' onkeyup="document.getElementById('preview').innerHTML=document.getElementById('textbox').value.replace(/\n/g,'<br />');" name='description' class='arial f12' style='width:400px;height:200px;resize:vertical;'></textarea></div>
```

/g makes it a global replace (all occurrences)